# Can I install latest Security Patch without Feature pack in SharePoint 2016?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, cumulative-update, patching

I skipped one Feature Pack (e.g Feature Pack 2), but installed latest security update in SharePoint 2016. Is there any issue will be? Let me explain you: I have installed latest January 2022 Patch (Language Independent Files) Directly without installed September 2017 Patch (Language Independent Files) - Feature Pack 2 . Can I install latest June 2022 patch directly again?

Thanks,

Srinivas.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the latest non-locale and locale-specific patch. In other words, you cannot skip FP2. If you do not install the latest locale-specific patch (there isn't always one for a given month), you may run into errors, such as missing resource strings, errors on pages, etc.

For example, if there is a non-locale *and* local-specific patch for June 2022, you *must* install both. If there is only a non-locale patch for June 2022, you must install the *last available* (say May 2022) locale-specific patch.

Comment: Thanks @Trevor Seward, Can I install  FP 2 now.( Already installed Jan 2022 security  update)